# System.IO.FileNotFoundException .NetCore 1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.1, .net-core-1.1

I'm new to .NetCore ,currently building a Webapi application using Asp.NetCore 1.1 which was release few days ago. I have referenced few class library which was developed in .net 4.5.2

When i run the application i'm getting below error when i invoke a controller. please help to resolve this.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   ', Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=22b71681a01d2a47'. The system cannot find the file
>   specified. File name: ', Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=22b71681a01d2a47'    at
>   System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig,
>   RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)    at
>   System.Signature..ctor(IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType
>   declaringType)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.get_Signature()    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.GetParametersNoCopy()    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.GetParameters()    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.FindApplicableConstructor(Type
>   instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes, ConstructorInfo&
>   matchingConstructor, Nullable`1[]& parameterMap)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(Type
>   instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(Type
>   instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes)    at
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.TypeActivatorCache.CreateInstance[TInstance](IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider, Type implementationType)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(ControllerContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.d__2.MoveNext()

Comment: Any chance you could provide code of the minimal solution that would allow us to replicate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you build a *.NET Core application you have something called the `.net standard`. This .NET Standard is a set of APIs that all .NET platforms have to implement. This unifies the .NET platforms and prevents future fragmentation.

According to this table:

[image: alt]

The .NET Framework 4.5.2 should be compatible with the `.NET Standard 1.2` or the `.NET Standard 1.3`.

If any of this standard works try changing the targeting version of your dll to `.NET Framework 4.5.1` or `.NET Framework 4.6`.

There is a usefull link about the what is the NET Standard: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/